# TypeError with (0 , _genMapping.maybeAddMapping) is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, types

I'm getting errors in the app which I cannot help myself with fixing it. What might be the reason of 2 below errors? There are similar, the root-directory of them differs.

```
TypeError: C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\src\pages\cv-list\list\list.js: (0 , _genMapping.maybeAddMapping) is not a function
ERROR in ./src/pages/cv-list/list/list.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\src\pages\cv-list\list\list.js: (0 , _genMapping.maybeAddMapping) is not a function
    at SourceMap.mark (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\source-map.js:49:37)
    at Buffer._mark (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:142:60)
    at Buffer._append (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:121:12)
    at Buffer.append (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:82:10)
    at Generator._append (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\printer.js:192:52)
    at Generator.word (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\printer.js:100:10)
    at Generator.VariableDeclaration (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\generators\statements.js:296:8)
    at C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\printer.js:309:19
    at Buffer.withSource (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:212:5)
Failed to compile.

TypeError: C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\src\pages\cv-list\list\list.js: (0 , _genMapping.maybeAddMapping) is not a function
ERROR in ./src/pages/cv-list/list/list.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\src\pages\cv-list\list\list.js: (0 , _genMapping.maybeAddMapping) is not a function
    at SourceMap.mark (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\source-map.js:49:37)
    at Buffer._mark (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:142:60)
    at Buffer._append (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:121:12)
    at Buffer.append (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:82:10)
    at Generator._append (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\printer.js:192:52)
    at Generator.word (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\printer.js:100:10)
    at Generator.VariableDeclaration (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\generators\statements.js:296:8)
    at C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\printer.js:309:19
    at Buffer.withSource (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\buffer.js:212:5)
    at Generator.withSource (C:\Users\marci\OneDrive\Pulpit\300B\BDB\bdb-front\node_modules\@babel\generator\lib\printer.js:176:15)
```

Just in case, here is my package.json

```
  {
  "name": "bdb-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-date-math": "^1.5.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.39",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "js-joda": "^1.11.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "primeflex": "^3.1.0",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primereact": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-export-excel": "^0.5.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

it occurred when I started to work on react-export-table, my intention is to export data which is an array of objects into excel file. Below You can find the codesandbox which reflects the code I have in my app:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cannon-zohev8?file=/src/App.js

thanks a lot !

Comment: Create Minimal reproductive example. Without your code, we cannot tell you what you are doing wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have just updated the question text

Answer (score 2):

There's a similar question answered here: [I'm getting the error "_genMapping.maybeAddMapping is not a function" when I try to collect coverage from jest tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308375/im-getting-the-error-genmapping-maybeaddmapping-is-not-a-function-when-i-try)

Delete the node_modules folder and re-run `yarn`.
(or `npm install`, just match what your repo normally uses)

I did not delete the lock file, just rebuilding node_modules worked for me.